# Manytoone lazy property not loaded using join fetch jpql in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, lazy-loading, jpql, many-to-one

I'm using spring boot 2.3.0, hibernate 5 and MySQL 8.0
I'm trying to initialize a ManyToOne relationship using join fetch in my JQPL query but it doesn't work because the entity is not loaded.

In the entity i have:

```
@Entity
public class Academic_Record {

    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Product product;

.....
```

In the repository:

```
@Query(value = "select ar from Academic_Record ar " +
        "join fetch ar.product p " +
        "where ar.enrollmentStudent.id = :enrollmentStudentId " +
        "and ar.product.id = :productId")
Academic_Record findByEnrollmentStudentIdAndProductIdWithProduct(Long enrollmentStudentId, Integer productId);
```

But if try:

```
Academic_Record academicRecord = academicRecordDao.findByEnrollmentStudentIdAndProductIdWithProduct(1,2);
```

when i watch product property of academicRecord in debug mode, I only see a proxy object and not the product loaded.

What's wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for `FetchType.LAZY`, the proxy will be resolved when you try to get the product. Use `FetchType.EAGER` instead if you want to load the product at the same time.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
private Product product;
```